# What is the CompletableFuture equivalent for Kotlin coroutines?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Normally, I would do something like this:

```
var future: CompletableFuture<String>? = null;

fun onMessage(message: String) {
    future?.complete(message)
}

fun test() {
    future = CompletableFuture<String>()
    val result = future?.get() // onMessage is called in the meantime
}
```

How could I do the same in Kotlin coroutines? I already tried things like `Deferred`, but they don't offer a `complete`-like function.

Comment: [CompletableDeferred](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-completable-deferred/index.html)

Comment: @GeorgeLeung CompletableDeferred was the solution, thanks! If you want to answer this question, I will accept your answer.